# What is the Ruby equivalent of the Python max() function?

Tags: ruby, search

What I want to do is assign a score to all the items in an array, and then select the highest scoring one.

```
def score(r, string)
    return some_calculation(r, string)
end

pool = a_list_of_strings()
data = unrelated_list_of_strings()
```

And now I can get the highest score in the array with

```
pool.map{|r| score(r, data)}.max
```

but that doesn't tell me which value has that score. If this were Python, I could use

```
max(pool, key=score)
```

This is not Python, so what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pool.max_by{|r| score(r, data)}
```